# Is there any Spring Retry documentation?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm interested in finding out more about Spring Retry. Is there any documentation anywhere? All I can find is the source code in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-retry).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring reference docs for Spring Retry are here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/

Comment: Note: these aren't for Spring Retry as a separate project, but rather when it was still part of Spring Batch.

Comment: The javadocs are here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-retry/docs/api/current/

Comment: That's now the same (1.1.2 Javadocs as Apr 1, 2016). And no "reference documentation", just Javadocs.

Comment: That's not current: The latest version is 1.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the javadocs you can find them here: [org.springframework.retry : spring-retry](http://javadox.com/org.springframework.retry/spring-retry/1.0.2.RELEASE/overview-summary.html)

Hope it helps,
Nicolás

Comment: A newer version is hosted on the Spring site: http://static.springsource.org/spring-retry/docs/api/current/

Comment: @GaryRussell: Not the newest; 1.2.2 is out.

Comment: Thanks; fixed; that old URL now redirects to https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/